# Calling IPython.core.display

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

In a Jupypter notebook, I am  calling the 'display' object from IPython.core.display as per the following line:

```
display(‘This is a test’)
```

The output is as expected as follows without explicitly calling for it via 'import'

```
‘This is a test’
```

However in the Eclipse IDE, I attempting to do the same thing explicitly as ‘display’ as follows:

```
import IPython.core.display as display
display(‘This is a test’)
```

The result in this case is an error as follows:

```
display('This is a test')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How can I get the display object to work as it does in the Jupyter notebook, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
import IPython.core.display as display
```

use the following

```
from IPython.core.display import display
```